# Django issue with gettext unable to read .mo files

Tags: django, python-2.7

To give a bit of context, I'm working in internship on the upgrade of a Django app from 1.4.22 to 1.11 and python 2 to 3.

The project wasn't well factored, and when I tried to refactor it, I got a strange stack :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/djangoproject/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/djangoproject/instance/models.py", line 54, in <module>
    YEARS += [(str(yr), _(u"n+%(year)d") % {'year': yr}) for yr in range(1, 20)]
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 179, in __mod__
    return six.text_type(self) % rhs
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 144, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 83, in ugettext
    return _trans.ugettext(message)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 325, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 306, in do_translate
    _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 209, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 195, in _fetch
    res = _merge(apppath)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in _merge
    t = _translation(path)
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _translation
    t = gettext_module.translation('django', path, [loc], DjangoTranslation)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gettext.py", line 554, in translation
    t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
  File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 107, in __init__
    gettext_module.GNUTranslations.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gettext.py", line 255, in __init__
    self._parse(fp)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gettext.py", line 348, in _parse
    magic = unpack('<I', buf[:4])[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

When I tried to debug, with step by step mode, I saw that the issue is at the line

```
File "/home/antonin/Developpement/Projet/djangoproject2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 107, in __init__
    gettext_module.GNUTranslations.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
```

where fp.read() receive a u'path/to/file.po' (path which is correct) and return a empty buffer. But I don't see any reasons why this appens.

Edit : thanks, håken, it was Indeed the .mo files that were corrupted. Problem solved.

Comment: Please edit your provide source code, or give example of what is causing the Trace to present such errors as well as the steps that lead you to it, it is not possible to help you without more information.

Comment: A .mo file might have become corrupted? Did you manually edit it? You can rebuild by using `django-admin compilemessages` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages